# Is it possible to combine Parse and ParseFiles templates in Go?

Tags: templates, go, go-templates

I have a `base.html` template stored in the file, with the following content:

```html
<!doctype HTML>
<html>
<head>
  <title>{{ template "title" }}</title>
</head>
<body>
  {{ template "content" }}
</body>
```

Also I have a template `post.html` to fill in the `content` section of `base.html` template:

```html
{{ define "title" }} Title {{ end }}
{{ define "content" }}
<p>Here is my content</p>
{{ end }}
```

I know how to combine the templates if these two templates are stored on disk as HTML files. I do something like this:

```golang
t, _ := template.ParseFiles(basePath, postPath)
t.ExecuteTemplate(w, "base", nil)
```

However, I also have a use case when I want to combine two templates, where one of them comes from the file and another one - from a string. For example:

```golang
baseTemplate, _ := template.ParseFiles(basePath)
contentTempalte, _ := template.New("content").Parse(`
{{ define "content" }}
<p>Here is my content</p>
{{ end }}
`)
// Is it possible to do something like this made up function?
// baseTemplate.ExecuteWith(os.Stdout, contentTemplate, nil)
```

I wonder if it possible to combine these two templates somehow together? Or any arbitrary instances of `template.Template`? I've never worked with Golang templates before, so the process is still a bit unclear to me.

Comment: Yes: https://golang.org/pkg/text/template/#Template.Parse. Just parse your string into the baseTemplate

Comment: Ah, right! I should read the docs more carefully...